# Where is the source code that performs access path selection in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

There must be a part in the query planner of Postgres that is responsible for identifying which index to use based on various information (relation, column name, operator class/family, statistics, etc.).

I know that the source code of Postgres is available online but I would like a direct link to the part that performs the access path selection. The codebase is big and I can't find the relevant part.

Comment: src/backend/optimizer/README

Comment: [README link](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/optimizer/README)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible index access paths are found in the function `create_index_paths` in [`src/backend/optimizer/path/indxpath.c`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/optimizer/path/indxpath.c;hb=HEAD).